# If statement: Condition is true, but code block is not executing

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a function that gives me a random number inbetween two numbers. That function works.
I have a conditional statement below the function that's supposed to change my variable from false to true, but when I console.log the variable, it is still false. My conditional statement is true, when I console.log actualGetRandom, it comes out to either 10 or 11, but the code between the curly braces is not executed. Not sure why and need some input. Thanks.

```js
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var isBetween10And11 = false;
var actualGetRandom = getRandomIntInclusive(10, 11);
if (actualGetRandom >= 10 && actualGetRandom <= 11) {
  console.log("I'm here");
  isBetween10and11 = true;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is executed. If you run the snippet, you will see the output. But you are assigning two different variables `isBetween10And11` and `isBetween10and11`. Mind the uppercase `A` and lowercase `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement is exectued!

There is a typo in your code which makes it inconsistent:

```
var isBetween10And11 = false;
...
    isBetween10and11 = true;
```

Definition of variable: `...And...`
Use of variable `...and...`

---

- Best way to avod this: use editor with autocompletion and use it a lot.
- Best way to spot it: Use a debugger

Comment: Dang I am using replit and when i highlight that variable all the other variables light up, and i assumed that meant the variables were correct. Thanks!